# Problemas de conexao pgsql no Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5

Estou tentando fazer conexão na base de dados pgsql pelo Laravel 5.1 mas está aparecendo um erro:

> PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

--

> in Connector.php line 55
>   at PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=carros', 'root', 'senha_do_root', array('0', '2', '0', false, '0')) in Connector.php line 55
>   at Connector->createConnection('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=carros', array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'database' => 'carros', 'username' => 'root', 'password' => 'senha_do_root', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false, 'name' => 'mysql'), array('0', '2', '0', false, '0')) in MySqlConnector.php line 22
>   at MySqlConnector->connect(array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'database' => 'carros', 'username' => 'root', 'password' => 'senha_do_root', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false, 'name' => 'mysql')) in ConnectionFactory.php line 60
>   at ConnectionFactory->createSingleConnection(array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'database' => 'carros', 'username' => 'root', 'password' => 'senha_do_root', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false, 'name' => 'mysql')) in ConnectionFactory.php line 49
>   at ConnectionFactory->make(array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'database' => 'carros', 'username' => 'root', 'password' => 'senha_do_root', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false), 'mysql') in DatabaseManager.php line 175

Meu arquivo **.env** está assim:

```
    DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
    DB_PORT=5432
    DB_DATABASE=carros
    DB_USERNAME=root
    DB_PASSWORD=senha_do_root
```

E meu arquivo **database** está assim:

```
    'pgsql' => [
        'driver'   => 'pgsql',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port'      => '5432',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'carros'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'senha_do_root'),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
        'schema'   => 'public',
    ],
```

Comment: Seu dsn mostra uma conexão para mysql, existe um usuário root no postgres? o usuário padrão é postgres.

Comment: acabei de verificar mo postgres e existe um usuario root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

talvez seu arquivo config/database.php, no atributo default esteja assim:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
```

caso positivo, troque para

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),
```

Comment: Realmente eu havia esquecido de trocar mas agora trouxe o erro

> PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
could not find driver



in Connector.php line 55
at PDO->__construct('pgsql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=carros', 'root', 'senha_do_root', array('0', '2', '0', false)) in Connector.php line 55

Comment: @BJJ olhe no seu php.ini e verifique se as seguintes linhas estão descomentadas (sem o ";" na frente):

`extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll`
  
`extension=php_pgsql.dll`

Comment: se estiverem comentadas, retire o ";" da frente e reinicie o apache.

Comment: Deu certo Valeu!!

Comment: @BJJ  por favor, marque minha resposta como resposta aceita. Obrigado